# find best distance in given points

Tags: algorithm

I have a sequence of azimuth angles ranging from 0 to 180, then from -170 to -10, totaling 36 angles. In some cases, certain azimuth angles may be unavailable. I aim to choose **N** points from the available set and determine the maximum sum of distances between these points. For instance, if all points are valid, selecting N=4 would yield 0, 90, 180, and -90, ensuring maximum distance between them

how can I find solution for **N** points in given valid set of angles and get maximum distance ?

My solution was trying all combination C(valid_points, N) and get the maximum distance one.
I am looking for fast reliable solution because when N gets greater, cost becomes high.

Maybe it can be solved through auction algorithm

Comment: Why wouldn't, for example, 10, 100, -170 & -80 satisfy your example?

Comment: Please provide example(s) where not "all points are valid".

Comment: "In some cases, certain azimuth angles may be unavailable." I have written it in example. It could be 0  10 20 30 40 50 60 70 90 130 160 -90 -30 only available for example. 

As you wrote 10 100 -170 -80 could be not valid points in some cases. I need an algorithm that finds max distance in any given valid points.